# PowerShell Sum Array That Already Contains MBs

Tags: arrays, powershell, sum

I have an array that contains MBs already in the values.  This is how MS DPM returns data written to a tape.  I would like to sum them together.  Is there an easy one liner to accommodate for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MB` is a recognized numeric suffix in PowerShell's native grammar, so you can parse and evaluate your size strings with `Invoke-Expression`:

```
PS ~> Invoke-Expression '2401927.56MB'
2517924115906.56
```

You'll want to do some basic input validation to make sure it's actually a numeric sequence, and remove the thousand separator:

```
$Tapes.DataWrittenDisplayString |ForEach-Object {
    # remove commas and whitespace
    $dataWritten = $_ -replace '[,\s]'
    # ensure it's actually a number in the expected format
    if($dataWritten -match '^\d+(?:\.\d+)?[kmgtp]b$'){
        # let PowerShell do the rest
        $dataWritten |Invoke-Expression
    }
}
```